# NSDecimalNumber: summing two NaNs results in overflow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdecimalnumber

For some odd reason, I receive an NSDecimalNumberOverflowException from the following:

```
NSDecimalNumber *a = [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
NSDecimalNumber *b = [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
NSLog(@"%@",[a decimalNumberByAdding:b]);
```

This seems unexpected to me since the documentation for NSDecimalNumber's notANumber states that any arithmetic operation receiving a NaN as an argument returns a NaN...

I receive the same error for 1+NaN and NaN+1...thankfully 1+1 still gives 2.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Could it be that it is creating a *signaling* NaN vs. a *quiet* NaN? These concepts exist in IEEE-754, not sure about NSDecimalNumber. What happens if you do `[x decimalNumberByAdding: x]` where `x` is the NSDecimalNumber created byte `1.0/0`?

Comment: Given the documentation's wording, I would think a quiet NaN would be created, but the idea of a signaling NaN makes more sense here. As for 1.0/0, I receive a divide by zero exception. It seems I simply need to account for these exceptions explicitly, rather than expect NSDecimalNumber's arithmetic to do so for me.

Comment: Please suggest your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Shouldn't have been div-by-zero, 1.0/0.0 -> ?

Comment: I'm using NSDecimalNumber's method for performing the division, which will give such exceptions when dividing by zero. At any rate, using NSDecimalNumberHandler to suppress exceptions and allow quiet NaNs to be used for calculation appears to have solved the problem and clarified the confusion. Please move your original comment to an answer so I may mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per posters request:

Could it be that it is creating a *signaling* NaN vs. a *quiet* NaN? These concepts exist in IEEE-754, not sure about NSDecimalNumber. What happens if you do `[x decimalNumberByAdding: x]` where x is the NSDecimalNumber created byte 1.0/0?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to try to perform arithmetic on a NaN value?  NaN is an error value.

Comment: The motivation for performing arithmetic with a NaN value is beside the point.

Comment: `NaN` isn't necessarily an error value. IEEE-754 specifies both "quiet" and "signaling" forms. The `NaN` may be expected to fall-through, not hard-coded as above.